# Angular DatePipe show new Date data from API

Tags: angular, rest, date-pipe

I think this question has bean asked many time before. I have implemented DatePipe in my angular project, formating is correct only it shows the current Date and this is not what i want and is not the date that i receive from my rest services. I get from the REST service (createdOn) a date that is in the past. This is my code:

TS

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
post: Postpayload;
newDateFormat: string;
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute,
          private postService: PostService, public datepipe: DatePipe) {
            this.post = {
              createdOn: new Date()
            };
            this.newDateFormat = this.datepipe.transform(this.post.createdOn, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
         }
 }
```

PostPayload

```
export class Postpayload {
id: number;
content: string;
title: string;
username: string;
createdOn: Date;
```

}

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.router.params.subscribe( params => {
  this.permaLink = params.id;
});
  this.postService.getPost(this.permaLink).subscribe( (  data:Postpayload) 
  => {
  this.post = data;
   }, (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('failure response');
   });
  }
```

HTML

```
<p>{{ newDateFormat }}</p>
```

This results me a current date or todays date, my question is how do i format the date of this.post.createdOn that i receive from my rest Api service call. When i am not using DatePipe then it shows correct date but i dont want this default full style date format.

PostService

```
getPost(permaLink: number): Observable<Postpayload> {
return this.http.get<Postpayload>(this.url + 'get/' + permaLink);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're doing the date pipe in the class, but are you able to move it to your dom?

```
<p>{{ newDateFormat | date:"dd-MM-yyyy" }}</p>
```

Comment: no diffrentses even if use pipe inside html i wil still the current date , todays date. that becouse of calling the new Date. So the question is actualy how can i properly instantiat fiel createdOn from PostPayload in calling method, without new Date().

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the date from your service, but you are instantiating `new Date` instance. What you are doing here is exactly what is expected from `new Date()` - to set the current date. Actually to get your data from Service, you should show us how your postService is implemented. So the call could be something like this, assuming `getPost` from service is returning `Observable`:

```
         postService.getPost().subscribe( (postPayload) => {
                this.post = {
                   createdOn: postPayload.createdOn
                };
                this.newDateFormat =this.datepipe.transform(this.post.createdOn, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
          }
```

Comment: PostService

'getPost(permaLink: number): Observable<Postpayload> {
    return this.http.get<Postpayload>(this.url + 'get/' + permaLink);
  }'

once again i dont have problems with retreving my correct from the post service for the date. if i dont use DatePipe it shows me the correct date.

Comment: but as I said, you are not consuming your post service and `getPost` at all. Not in the code that you showed in your post.

Comment: i am consuming getPost, i have edit my post and added the concuming part of the code now you have full code. but this code is not necessary to show because it obvious. Like i sayt it works without DatePipe.

Answer (score 0):

So i have solved my problem , for those who are still interested.

I decided to use DatePipe straight in HTML.

{{ post.createdOn | date:'mediumDate'}}

in component.ts i don't instantiate createdOn at all with new Date(). I also changed createdOn in Postpayload to type any.

On the backend of my web application i have improved json by adding @JsonFormat(pattern="MM-dd-yyyy") on field createdOn, if i don't use JsonFormat the DatePipe will not be able to format correctly.